# How to send data to GUI

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

My code looks like this:

```js
signup.post('/signup', urlendcodedParser, async(req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const age = req.body.age;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const fullname = req.body.fullname;
    
   const data = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM allusers WHERE username = $1", [username])
   if(data.rows[0] === undefined){
    await pool.query("INSERT INTO allusers (username, userpassword, email, fullname, age) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *", [username, password ,email, fullname, age]).catch(err => console.log(err))
   console.log("account created successfully")
   }
  else{
    console.log("username is taken")
  }
  
    
   
 
})
```

If username is taken I want to send "Username is taken" to my react.js GUI.
Can my react GUI recive POST request? If not so what are other ways I can do it

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is make an endpoint "username is already taken", that checks wether or not the name is taken.

In your GUI, whenever you are done typing, you can then validate if the name is taken x ms after the last user input so the backend is not spammed.

Alternatively, just send an error response with a message back to the GUI, that you can catch, its just not as pretty.